# How can i use *ngIf in the host of my Directive?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a Directive that removes/adds itself to the DOM like *ngIf would do. What i have so far is:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]',
    host: {
        '[hidden]': 'hidden',
    }
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(private myService : MyService) {
  }

  hidden() {
    return !this.myService.valid;
  }
```

But what i need is something like:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]',
    host: {
        '*ngIf': 'hidden',
    }
})
...
```

Sadly i can not use `'*ngIf': 'hidden'` in `host` of Directive. The error i get is:

```
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
```

Also `'[ngIf]': 'hidden'` is not working.

So, how can i use ngIf in a Directive?

Comment: Directives can't be added/removed dynamically.

Comment: Günter's comment ^ should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  valid = true;
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[myIf]'
})
export class MyIfDirective {
  constructor(private myService: MyService, 
        private el:ElementRef,
        private view:ViewContainerRef,
        private template:TemplateRef<any>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    if(this.myService.valid) {
      this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      Peek A Boo: <h2 *myIf>Hello</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```